# XNA, tIDE and collision, oh my. Need some assistance

Tags: math, xna, 2d, collision

I am currently using tIDE for my tile map (http://tide.codeplex.com/) and am having trouble with collision using the tile index.

The tile index for the water is 12. My problem is there seems to be a big invisible block in the middle of the screen which blocks my character.

I can change the values in the PlayerSprite class:

```
            tileLocation = new Location((newPos.X - Collisionbox.Width / 2) / 64,
            (newPos.Y - Collisionbox.Height / 2) / 64);
```

and it shrinks this box, but the collision with tiles is uneven.
Try out my solution and you will see what I mean!

(Have to feed daughter but I will post a relative picture shortly)

You can download the solution >>> [My Solution](http://www.mediafire.com/?n4f4smkm2w0btuo)

Please excuse my sloppy coding. I plan on cleaning it up later lol.

EDIT:

I have realized it is drawing the 'blocking area' just a bit too far south.

I made an 'L' shape on a new map and I can follow it as compared to the water layout above it. How would I center it in the correct place?